# Anova with order between treatments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I want to analyse a regression model with categorical explanatory variable.
to be accurate, the model is as follows:

$y_{k,j}=\mu_k+\epsilon_{k,j}$

where $k$ is the number of different effects $(k>2)$
and $j=1,...,n_k$ is the number of observations in the $k$-th effect.

now,
the hypothesis test will be:

$H_0:\mu_1=\dots=\mu_k$

$H_1:\mu_1<\dots<\mu_k$

Does the described model defined in the literature? If the answer is positive, what is its name? Is there a proper procedure to test the above hypothesis?

Thanks very much.

Edit: I saw Bartholomew’s test and Jonckheere’s Test but haven't found any further information about them.